# Can I create a normalied image rotation matrix and then use it on multiple different images?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to store an affine transformation matrix that is independent of image size (normalized if you will) and then apply that to an image but I'm having problems with the math. It certainly seems possible to me. Here is my python code.

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread(filepath)

center = (0.4, 0.7)
angle = 39

#
# THIS WORKS
#
matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((center[0] * image.shape[1], center[1] * image.shape[0]), angle, 1.0)

image2 = cv2.warpAffine(image, matrix, dsize=(image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
cv2.imwrite("/home/ken/rotated.jpg", image2)

#
# BUT WHAT I WANT TO DO IS THIS such that matrix can be calculated and stored...
#
matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)

#
# ... and then when presented with an image, convert the matrix here to
# make it work with the current image size.
#
matrix = denormalize_matrix(matrix, image.shape) # <== DESIRED PSEUDO FUNCTION

image2= cv2.warpAffine(image, matrix, dsize=(image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))

cv2.imwrite("/home/ken/rotated_new.jpg", image2)
```

Is there some way to transform this matrix once I know the actual size of the image I'm operating on?

Cheers.

Comment: I do not understand, how can you normalize for every possible rotation angle and for every possible scale and for every possible offset?  What do I now understand about your problem?

Comment: Maybe this is not possible but I was thinking that if I define my center as relative to the image size (and any offsets likewise) that I could calculate a rotation matrix and THEN transform that matrix into a matrix to do the actual work once the actual width and height are known. Just seems mathematically possible to me but maybe not?

Comment: You can put variables into a matrix, but would have to evaluate them when using the matrix in OpenCV in your script.

Comment: you need to sandwich the rotation matrix between two scaling matrices that transform from image space to normalized space and back, possibly including translation, if you only ever want to rotate around the center. be very careful though about aspect ratios. if you do this wrong, you'll get stretching effects and the rotation won't move in a circle but an ellipse. -- would you like an answer for this? I see you don't mark answers as "solutions" all that often.

Comment: Yes please. :) You had me scared about my etiquette here and just went back and reviewed all my questions. I did find 3 correct answers that I only upvoted but forgot to accept. 7 of them I answered myself (should one mark one's own solution?). The others were legitimately not answered. :) Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: yes, you can mark self-answers as solutions (if that solved your problem satisfactorily). I don't think that'll give you points but it's a definite signal to other people that you aren't waiting for a better answer. even if someone comes along and gives a better answer, you can change your mind. -- I'll spend some time on an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. It just needs a sequence of matrices to be composed. Matrices compose by matrix multiplication. Transforms are applied *to* images or points from *the left*, i.e.

```
v' = M v = M3 M2 M1 v
```

A sequence is "executed" outwards, from right to left.

A bunch of constructors for transformation matrices:

```
def rotate(degrees):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2, 0:3] = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((0,0), -degrees, 1.0)
    return T

def translate(tx, ty):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2,2] = (tx, ty)
    return T

def scale(s=1, sx=1, sy=1):
    T = np.diag([s*sx, s*sy, 1.0])
    return T
```

You'll need to decide what "normalized" space to work in. Making it range from `(-1,-1)` to `(+1,+1)` would be convenient because you wouldn't have to encode translations for any rotation around the center. I'll go with `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` for now.

If you want the output image to have a different size, then the "denormalization" isn't just the inverse of the "normalization" but uses different scale factors. You can also get a different output size as an "addon" matrix that scales from one size to another.

Note that I'm being sloppy with the scaling here. Pixel centers are integer coordinates. Images *start* at the top left corner of the top left pixel and *end* at the bottom right corner of the bottom right pixel. Proper scaling would involve small translations to account for this fact.

The normalization decides what happens to circles. If you scale each axis individually, then the image is stretched into a square, you'll get a unit circle inscribed into whatever aspect ratio your image has, i.e. rotation happens on an ellipse.

If you don't want that, you'll need to scale uniformly. You can do that by taking `max(width, height)`, then using that for the scale factor for both axes. However, now you've got the input image "letterboxed". This gives you a sense of the difference between the image, the space it is in, and what you're actually rotating (the image or the space) or what point you're rotating around.

```
def normalize(imshape, isotropic=False):
    h,w = imshape[:2]

    sx,sy = w, h

    if isotropic:
        #sx = sy = np.sqrt(w*h)
        sx = sy = max(w, h)
        cx,cy = (w-1)/2, (h-1)/2

    T = scale(sx=1/sx, sy=1/sy) # scale down

    if isotropic: # scale around center
        T = translate(+0.5, +0.5) @ T @ translate(-cx, -cy)

    return T
```

*Between* of those two matrices (normalization, denormalization), you put your desired transform (rotation and translations) that works in the normalized space.

```
center = (cx, cy) = (0.5, 0.9)
angle = 45

normalized_matrix = translate(+cx, +cy) @ rotate(angle) @ translate(-cx, -cy)
```

Now here's the two normalization options I've discussed above.

```
isotropic = False # or True
N1 = normalize(im.shape, isotropic=isotropic)
N2 = np.linalg.inv(N1)

H = N2 @ normalized_matrix @ N1 # homography matrix but only affine transform
M = H[0:2] # the affine content only

warped = cv.warpAffine(im, M, dsize=(w, h), flags=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Not isotropic: input space, normalized (stretched), rotated, output space (squashed)

[image: 1 input]
[image: 1 normal]
[image: 1 rotated]
[image: 1 output]

Isotropic: input space, normalized (letterbox), rotated, output space (cropped)

[image: 2 input]
[image: 2 normal]
[image: 2 rotated]
[image: 2 output]

The blue dot is the "expected" rotation center relative to output space... rotation happens in normalized space though.